# App Runs as Background Process Instead of as an App

Tags: windows-10, process

I have successfully installed and run a screen share app on both of my desktops. But, on my laptop, when I open the app, it runs as a background process instead of as an app (as seen in Task Manager). All 3 systems are running Windows 10 Pro. So, to be clear, I WANT THE APP TO ***NOT*** RUN AS A BACKGROUND PROCESSS. **I need it to run as an app (which is what it's supposed to do) so I can use it.** I've talked with the app provider's tech support people, uninstalled (and cleaned it out of the registry) several times..all with no success. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

1.Open setting in the Start Menu
2.Find Privacy and click it
3.Find the Background apps in the left options
4.Find the app you won't it run as background or just disable all
[image]